# iOS vertical center dynamic height stack layout in autolayout

Tags: xcode, autolayout, uistackview

I am trying to create a vertically and horizontally centered stack view with dynamic height content. Something like this:

[image]

I and I am almost there, but the problem is that when I add a button which height should be dynamic (scale with label) I get this: (Note the overlapping buttons).

[image]

Here's what I currently have:

[image]

Without that button with the long label, the view looks good. Now I've read about the concepts of how the auto layout works, that It needs to know the height of the content to center it. But about the cases when the content height is unknown?

Comment: Have you tried adding a vertical constraint >= some min value to your button that has a dynamic height?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, it didn't work.

Comment: It looks like your "Checkbox" button object is missing a constraint or two - probably, you're using a container view, and its height is not being expanded by the multiline label.  Can you show the code and/or IB layout for your Checkbox object?

Comment: Do you mean the .storyboard XML file?

Comment: @antanas_sepikas - how is your Checkbox object set up? Is it a view with a button and label as subviews? Or is it a standard `UIButton` with the label set to multiline?

Comment: It's a UIButton

Answer (score -1):

Setting the `titleLabel` of a `UIButton` to multi-line (changing Line Break to Word Wrap) doesn't change the `intrinsicContentSize` of the button, so you have to do it yourself.

Here is one approach. Subclass `UIButton` like this:

```
class CheckboxButton: UIButton {

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return titleLabel?.intrinsicContentSize ?? CGSize.zero
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = titleLabel?.frame.size.width ?? 0
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }

}
```

You can confirm the sizing is being done correctly by giving your button a background color (during development) to clearly see its bounds / frame.

After that, the spacing should be handled correctly by auto-layout.